# Java_Fill an array by getters

Tags: java, arrays, loops, getter, getter-setter

Trying to fill an array using getter, the problem the array is full with the same number and if the value change in the second input the hole array changes again :

```
public class Payment {

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
private int operationNum = 0;
private int subOperationNum = 0;
private double reMoney = 0;

public int getOperationNum() {
    return operationNum;
}

public int getSubOperationNum() {
    return subOperationNum;
}

public double getReMoney() {
    return reMoney;
}

public void setOperationNum(int operationNum) {
    this.operationNum = operationNum;
}

public void setSubOperationNum(int subOperationNum) {
    this.subOperationNum = subOperationNum;
}

public void setReMoney(double reMoney) {
    this.reMoney = reMoney;
}

public void operationsLoop() {
    double [] a = new double[17];
    do {
        System.out.println("\n1- Cash");
        System.out.println("2- Car");
        System.out.println("3- Clothing");
        System.out.println("4- Credit Card");
        System.out.println("5- Food");
        System.out.println("6- Education");
        System.out.println("7- Electronics");
        System.out.println("8- Groceries");
        System.out.println("9- Health & Fitness");
        System.out.println("10- Medical");
        System.out.println("11- Travel");
        System.out.println("12- Utilities");
        System.out.println("13- Finish");
        System.out.print("\nEnter the number of operation : ");
        this.setOperationNum(kb.nextInt());
        this.operation2();
        this.operation12();
        this.collectReMoney();
        **for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){
            a[i] = this.getReMoney();
            System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
        }**
    } while (operationNum < 13);
}

public void operation2() {
    if (this.getOperationNum() == 2) {
        System.out.println("\t1- Gas");
        System.out.println("\t2- Repair");
        System.out.println("\t3- Monthly Payment");
        System.out.print("\nEnter your chose : ");
        this.setSubOperationNum(kb.nextInt());
    }
}

public void operation12() {
    if (this.getOperationNum() == 12) {
        System.out.println("\t1- Electricity");
        System.out.println("\t2- Gas");
        System.out.println("\t3- Telephone");
        System.out.println("\t4- Water");
        System.out.print("\nEnter your chose : ");
        this.setSubOperationNum(kb.nextInt());
    }
}


public void collectReMoney() {
    if (this.getOperationNum() == 1) {
        System.out.print("Withdraw = ");
        this.setReMoney(kb.nextDouble());
    } else if (this.getOperationNum() == 4 || (this.getOperationNum() == 2 && this.getSubOperationNum() == 3)) {
        System.out.print("Payment = ");
        this.setReMoney(kb.nextDouble());
    } else if (this.getOperationNum() == 9 || this.getOperationNum() == 10) {
        System.out.print("Pay = ");
        this.setReMoney(kb.nextDouble());
    } else if (this.getOperationNum() != 13) {
        System.out.print("Spend = ");
        this.setReMoney(kb.nextDouble());
    }
}
```

and if I add to the array loop "this.setReMoney(0);" only the first value change

when the user enter a value i want to insert it in the array according to the operation number and the rest values of the other operations should be zero

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve .

Comment: `double reMoney` is not an array its a variable which can hold only one single value .

Comment: @cyroxis when the user enter a value i want to insert it in the array according to the operation number and the rest  values of the other operations should be zero

Comment: @Priyamal i want to insert each value of reMoney to another array so i can use it later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop you are assigning the same number to each of the elements of the array, to avoid that you should take the assigning operation outside the for loop:

```
a[operationNum - 1] = this.getReMoney();
for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){
    System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
}
```

Also, make sure that you check for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the case the user selects an option number grater than the size of the array.

Comment: thank you ... the array now will insert the values , as you can see in operation 2 and 12 the user also needs to choose an action, so will it work for the sub operations two ??

Comment: It wont, it will overwrite whatever value is stored on position (2-1) and (12-1). You could perhaps create additional arrays for options 2 and 12. Or append the additional values on the space that's left from the original array.

Comment: so I need to create another array for 2 and 12 to get there values without overwriting ??